# Is it a good practice to use __annotations__.keys() for __slots__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slots

Recently I learned about `__slots__`, and started using them on my codes.
And I came up with this idea of using annotations for slots.

```py
class Foo:
    bar: int
    baz: str
    __slots__ = __annotations__.keys()
```

This allows me to change attributes without caring about `__slots__`.
But none of the codes I've seen so far uses this technique,
and just uses straightfoward `__slots__ = ('attr1', 'attr2')`.

So I began wondering if there is a flaw/drawback to this useful trick.
Perhaps the type of `__slots__` affect performance? Everyone seems to be using tuple of str.

Comment: It's a little kinky, but hey, if it does what you want, we're all consenting adults here.

Comment: linters and type checkers will likely be unhappy with that idea (`mypy` for instance complains)

Comment: @AnthonySottile, looks like you can get MyPy to stop complaining just by putting `__annotations__: dict[str, Any]` right above `__slots__ = __annotations__.keys()`.

Comment: that might work today, but iirc mypy is working on better validation of `__slots__` and it's going to have no idea what you mean by `__annotations__.keys()` (also it's arguably a bug that mypy doesn't know that `__annotations__` is in scope there and once that's fixed you'd get a redefinition error)

Comment: @AnthonySottile fair enough — that's useful information, thanks. Agree that the current behaviour wrt `__annotations__` seems arguably a bit of a bug.